# Drag and Drop incorrect behaviour

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I'm making an app using phonegap and jquery mobile and I have one page with a drag & drop system.

The draggables are created dynamically. All is working fine, I can drag the items from a jquery Panel to a Containner DIV.

**The problem:** for some reason I can't explain some of the times I drop a new draggable in the container the droppable randomly changes the position of some of the others draggables already dropped inside the container.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery.ajax({
           url: '<my_url_request>',
           type: 'GET',
           dataType: 'jsonp',
           success: function(data) {
               console.log(data);

               var players = [];

               $.each(data.posts, function(i, item) {
                     players.push('<div id="player_' + item.id + '" class="ui-draggable player" data-id="' + item.id + '"><img src="' + item.thumbnail_images.medium_large.url + '" width="100%" /><div id="player_name">' + item.title + '</div></div>');
               });  // close each()

               $('#jogadores').append( players.join('') );
               $('#jogadores').trigger('create');

               $( ".ui-draggable" ).draggable({
                            containment: "#soccer_container", 
                            cursor: "move",
                            zIndex: 100
               });  

               $("#soccer_container").droppable({
                    accept: ".ui-draggable",
                    drop: function(event, ui) {        
                        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
                    }
               });        
           },

           error: function(data){
             console.log(data);
           }
});
```

**EDIT 1:**

You can check the behaviour here: [here](http://lemingonline.com/toscarias/www/#convocatoria)

Comment: please share the working code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Your post with index zero doesn't have an thumbnail_images entry

[image]

Comment: you checked the link when i was working on that register, it's already fixed, but that isn't the problem...